# How to create or update the value of an element using XmlPoke

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

In an MSBuild target, I need to set the value of an XML element to a specific value. If that element does not exist I need to create it. I'm trying to achieve this using MSBuild's [`XmlPoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/xmlpoke-task) task but it only works if the element exists already. Here's an example:

XML content to update:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest>
  <metadata>
    <name>whatever</name>
    <version>1.2.3.4</version>
  </metadata>
</manifest>
```

Using `XmlPoke` as shown below, I can successfully set the value of the `version` element:

```xml
<XmlPoke
  XmlInputPath="$(XmlFilePath)"
  Query="/manifest/metadata/version"
  Value="4.3.2.1" />
```

The result of that looks as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest>
  <metadata>
    <name>whatever</name>
    <version>4.3.2.1</version>
  </metadata>
</manifest>
```

However, if the input is missing the `version` element, as shown below, the `XmlPoke` task just doesn't do anything:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest>
  <metadata>
    <name>whatever</name>
  </metadata>
</manifest>
```

How can I create the `version` element and set it to `4.3.2.1` if it does not exist or just set it to `4.3.2.1` if it does exist using MSBuild standard functionality?

---

**Edit:**

The accepted answer with combining both `XmlPeek` and `XmlPoke` works. Based on that answer, here's the code that inserts or updates the value:

```xml
<XmlPeek
   XmlInputPath="$(XmlFilePath)"
   Query="/manifest/metadata/version">
   <Output
      TaskParameter="Result"
      ItemName="VersionEntry" />
</XmlPeek>
<XmlPoke
   Condition="'@(VersionEntry)' != ''"
   XmlInputPath="$(XmlFilePath)"
   Query="/manifest/metadata/version"
   Value="4.3.2.1" />
<XmlPoke
   Condition="'@(VersionEntry)' == ''"
   XmlInputPath="$(XmlFilePath)"
   Query="/manifest/metadata"
   Value="&lt;Name&gt;whatever&lt;/Name&gt;&lt;Version&gt;4.3.2.1&lt;/Version&gt;" />
```

Comment: When `Condition="'@(VersionEntry)' == ''"` you should `XmlPeek` on '/manifest/metadata'. As written in the **Edit**, `<metadata><name>whatever</name></metadata>` is changed to `<metadata><version>4.3.2.1</version></metadata>` and `name` is lost.

Comment: @JonathanDodds Right, you are correct with this. I've edited the code above to address this. Because I always know the value of the `name` element I just add both the `name` and `version` elements as child nodes of the `metadata` element in case that the `version` element does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XmlPoke` uses the specified XPath, the `Query`, to find matching nodes. If it finds a node, it replaces the `InnerXml` with the specified `Value`. It will do this for each match. If there are no matches, `XmlPoke` does nothing.

**An approach using standard MSBuild functionality:**

Use `XmlPeek` to test for `/manifest/metadata/version`.

If `version` exists, then use `XmlPoke` to update.

If `version` does not exist:

1. Use `XmlPeek` to get the contents of `/manifest/metadata`.
2. Create a replacement value consisting of the existing contents of `metadata` with `<version>$(ver)</version>` appended.
3. Use `XmlPoke` to update `/manifest/metadata`.

If that seems cumbersome, you could write an inline task that 'upserts' the version.